# Why is coffeescript prepending "1" for the constructor argument

Tags: coffeescript

```
class MyController
  constructor: (@foo) ->
```

translates to (this is good)

```
var MyController;

MyController = (function() {
  function MyController(foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  return MyController;
})();
```

But the following code

```
class MyController
  constructor: (@foo) ->
    @bar = foo
```

translates to

```
var MyController;

MyController = (function() {
  function MyController(foo1) { //foo1 ??
    this.foo = foo1;
    this.bar = foo; //Now due to this, the compiler throws up!
  }

  return MyController;

})();
```

While I was expecting the following conversion

```
var MyController;

MyController = (function() {
  function MyController(foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = foo;
  }

  return MyController;
})();
```

Is this a bug in compilation or am I missing something?

Here's the [link](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20MyController%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20(%40foo)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%40bar%20%3D%20foo%0A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with CS compilator here, the only problem is that your second example is incorrect.

Let's have a closer look at your code:

```coffee
class MyController
  constructor: (@foo) ->
    @bar = foo
```

First, you're assigning `@foo` to the first argument, which is fine.

But then you're assigning `@bar` to some global `foo` variable, which is not defined anywhere in your code.

CS renamed `foo` to `foo1` to avoid naming collision with global `foo` variable.

Probably you wanted something like this instead:

```coffee
class MyController
  constructor: (@foo) ->
    @bar = @foo
```

**Update:**

`(@foo) ->` is a syntactic sugar for assigning first argument value to `this.foo`. Naturally, CS uses temp variable to carry this assignment, though the only thing guaranteed about the name of this temp variable is that it won't collide with any of your own variables.

As for your first example, the following code should explain why CS behaves correctly there:

```coffee
foo = 42

class MyController
  constructor: (@foo) ->
    @bar = foo
```

Comment: I'm actually using `@bar = @foo` right now. But since it works [in this case](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20MyController%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20(foo)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%40bar%20%3D%20foo%0A) where the foo is being picked from the constructor argument, it fails when I replace `foo` with `@foo`

Comment: Also when I'm assigning `@foo` to first argument, technically `foo` is the first argument right? `@foo` is syntactic sugar for `this.foo = foo`. So, I thought it would pick up the `foo` from argument than assuming it as a global variable & avoiding naming collision

Comment: No, `(@foo) ->` means that the first argument is exactly `@foo`. You can't access it by any other name.

Comment: See the 1.9.0 section of the [CoffeeScript Change Log](http://coffeescript.org/#changelog). An `@foo` parameter used to be available as the `foo` local variable.

Comment: @ Leonid: Makes sense now. @muistooshort thanks for pointing that out.